# Creating a proxy object on the array with data downloaded from api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuejs3

I don't know why after saving the data downloaded from api to the table, the table is closed in the proxy object.

```
data() {
    return {
      date: [],
  },

async dataToChart(code){
   try{
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/${code}`);
      const data = await response.json();

      data.forEach((el, i) => {
      if(i > 250){
        this.date.push(el.Date)
      }
    });
    }catch(error){
       console.log(error);
    }
  },
```

and when I pass this table to a child component and display it there using `console.log`, the proxy object pops up:

```
Proxy {}
    [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Array(49)
    [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not with your code or API, This(`Proxies`) is how Vue3 observes the data properties. Mostly all properties are converted to `Proxies` As far I know. If you want to know why `Proxies` being used, you can watch [this video](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/advanced-components/evan-you-on-proxies/), as Evan You(The creator of Vue) explains in a better way!! :-)

Proxies let's you intercept the object changes and do any actions accordingly.

To understand more about Proxies and stuff, you need to understand how [Vue reactivity](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#what-is-reactivity) works.

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

> The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object, which can intercept and redefine fundamental operations for that object.

Comment: I understand the reactivity in Vue 3 but am no longer able to extract data from my array in the subcomponent.